# Fast absolute difference of two uint8 arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy-arrays with `dtype=np.uint8` - like this:

```
img1=np.uint8(np.random.randint(0, 255, (480, 640)))
img2=np.uint8(np.random.randint(0, 255, (480, 640)))
```

And I want to build the ***positive* difference** of these arrays.

Here are my first two approches (and a third one for reference):

```
def differenceImageV1(img1, img2):
  diff=np.empty_like(img1)
  h, w=img1.shape
  for y in range(h):
    for x in range(w):
      if img1[y, x]<img2[y, x]: diff[y, x]=img2[y, x]-img1[y, x]
      else:                     diff[y, x]=img1[y, x]-img2[y, x]
  return(diff)

def differenceImageV2(img1, img2):
  return(np.uint8(np.absolute(np.int16(img1)-np.int16(img2))))

def differenceImageV3(img1, img2):  # fast - but wrong result
  return(img1-img2)
```

I get these execution times (and the sums to check, if they are equal):

```
  10x: 1893.54 ms  np.sum=26122208
1000x:  411.71 ms  np.sum=26122208
1000x:   26.60 ms  np.sum=39123624
```

Is there a way to get a correct result faster as with V2 ?

Comment: Not sure if it would really help that much, but you likely don't need the `np.int16(img2)` in `differenceImageV2`, and can just use `img2`. Also, are you using the [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) library for accurate timing results?

Comment: I'm aware of the overflow (underflow is when the difference between two floating point numbers is too small to become distinguishable). I mean the full statement would be `return(np.uint8(np.absolute(np.int16(img1)-img2)))`. `img1` is still casted to an `int16`, so the result will be an `int16` and can allow the same negative numbers that doing the cast beforehand will do. `np.sum` gives the same result. It just doesn't take a copy of the entire array first. I shave off about 70 ms for 1000 loops.

Comment: you are right. I get the same result, if I do a `np.int16(img1)-img2`. The execution time goes down to 400.39 ms for 1000 loops. And no, I use `time.process_time()` here, because I do not care about one or ten milliseconds.

Comment: @dede: See my answer. Since I'm getting a 40x gap between V2 and V3 in my testing (way bigger than your 15x gap), I'd like to see how my solution performs on your testing setup.

Comment: @nneonneo: I get these values: V1(  10x: 1897.16 ms), V2(1000x:  412.73 ms), V3(1000x:   28.60 ms), V4(1000x: 1369.41 ms), V5(1000x:  253.97 ms), V6(1000x:  183.48 ms). Was this the data, you asked for?

Comment: Yes. It confirms that the V6 offers a nice speed up. Naturally it will be about 6x slower than V3 because it uses 6x more operations.

Comment: I now tried it with your procedure and got this: 
differenceImageV2 26125042 0.567810058594, differenceImageV3 39133866 0.249374866486, differenceImageV4 26125042 1.70322108269, differenceImageV5 26125042 1.18833398819, differenceImageV6 26125042 0.903051137924
Why are some of your execution times faster and some are slower?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's one approach that is significantly faster than `V2`: take `img1-img2`, and multiply by 1 or -1 depending on `img1>img2`. Here's how it is implemented:

```
def differenceImageV6(img1, img2):
  a = img1-img2
  b = np.uint8(img1<img2) * 254 + 1
  return a * b
```

A test harness for testing performance:

```
import numpy as np

img1=np.uint8(np.random.randint(0, 255, (480, 640)))
img2=np.uint8(np.random.randint(0, 255, (480, 640)))

def differenceImageV1(img1, img2):
  diff=np.empty_like(img1)
  h, w=img1.shape
  for y in range(h):
    for x in range(w):
      if img1[y, x]<img2[y, x]: diff[y, x]=img2[y, x]-img1[y, x]
      else:                     diff[y, x]=img1[y, x]-img2[y, x]
  return(diff)

def differenceImageV2(img1, img2):
  return(np.uint8(np.abs(np.int16(img1)-img2)))

def differenceImageV3(img1, img2):  # fast - but wrong result
  return(img1-img2)

def differenceImageV4(img1, img2):
  return np.where(img1>img2, img1-img2, img2-img1)

def differenceImageV5(img1, img2):
  a = img1-img2
  b = img2-img1
  c = img1>img2
  return a*c + b*(~c)

def differenceImageV6(img1, img2):
  a = img1-img2
  b = np.uint8(img1<img2) * 254 + 1
  return a * b

import timeit
def testit():
  for fn in [differenceImageV2, differenceImageV3, differenceImageV4, differenceImageV5, differenceImageV6]:
    print fn.__name__, np.sum(fn(img1, img2).astype('int64')),
    print timeit.timeit("%s(img1, img2)" % fn.__name__, "from test import img1, img2, %s" % fn.__name__, number=1000)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    testit()
```

and resulting performance numbers:

```
differenceImageV2 26071358 0.982538938522
differenceImageV3 39207702 0.0261280536652
differenceImageV4 26071358 1.36270809174
differenceImageV5 26071358 0.220561981201
differenceImageV6 26071358 0.154536962509
```

`differenceImageV6` is about 6x slower than the incorrect `differenceImageV3`, but still about 6x faster than the previous best `differenceImageV2`. `differenceImageV1` isn't tested because it's easily a few orders of magnitude slower than the rest.

Note: I included an `np.where` approach for comparison; I thought it might have good performance but it turns out to be fairly poor. It seems that performing slicing by a boolean array is quite slow in NumPy.

Comment: I'm getting about 895 µs for `differenceImageV2`, while 645 µs for `differenceImageV6`. Regardless of actual speedup, I still applaud the numpy wizardry.

Comment: I like your V6 :-) ...but still trying to understand it ;-)

Comment: I think V6 will be faster if you do it as `a = img1 - img2; a[img1 < img2] *= 255`.

Comment: @dede The most fundamental bits are that multiplying by `255` with 8-bit math is equivalent to multiplying by `-1` and letting it overflow. `a` is the basic difference, and `b` is an array of either `1` or `255` based on if that element of `img1` is less than that element of `img2`.

Comment: @Jaime While ingenious, it's even slower than `differenceImageV2` on my machine.

Comment: @Jaime: That's what I had implemented initially, but that's easily slower than even V2 by a significant amount. Slicing with Boolean arrays is sloooooow.

Comment: At the moment the `differenceImageV6()` appears to be the same of `cv2.absdiff()`

Comment: @decadenza Is my case, `differenceImageV6()` takes 133 ms while `cv2.absdiff` takes only 21 ms, being pretty much the same speed as `differenceImageV3`. If you have opencv, use it!

Answer (score 11):

If you have `opencv` available, you can also use:

```
def differenceImageV4(img1, img2):
  return cv2.absdiff(img1, img2)
```

which is almost the same speed as `differenceImageV3`.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since the accepted answer so just FYI I did some comparisons on Python3.10 with OpenCV 4.6.0 and Numpy 1.23.0. The OpenCV version is clearly superior, running about as fast as the wrong version (*edit: just realized that's exactly what Jan Rüegg was pointing out, but I misread the numbering of the functions*). Also, the int16 version is now about as fast as the neat trick.

```py
from time import perf_counter

import cv2
import numpy as np


def wrong(img1, img2):  # fast - but wrong result
    return img1 - img2


def with_int16(img1, img2):
    return np.abs((img1.astype(np.int16) - img2.astype(np.int16))).astype(np.uint8)


def neat_trick(img1, img2):
    a = img1 - img2
    b = np.uint8(img1 < img2) * 254 + 1
    return a * b


def opencv(img1, img2):
    return cv2.absdiff(img1, img2)


def testit():
    for fn in [wrong, with_int16, neat_trick, opencv]:
        times = []
        np_random = np.random.RandomState(0)
        for _ in range(10000):
            img1 = np.uint8(np_random.randint(0, 255, (480, 640)))
            img2 = np.uint8(np_random.randint(0, 255, (480, 640)))
            start = perf_counter()
            fn(img1, img2)
            times.append(perf_counter() - start)
        print(f"{fn.__name__.rjust(10)}: [mean]: {np.mean(times):.3E}, [std] {np.std(times):.3E}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    testit()
```

Output:

```
     wrong: [mean]: 9.198E-06, [std] 1.765E-06
with_int16: [mean]: 6.072E-05, [std] 4.590E-06
neat_trick: [mean]: 5.746E-05, [std] 5.453E-06
    opencv: [mean]: 9.660E-06, [std] 1.589E-06
```

Answer (score 0):

Another version that's not quite as fast as V3 but faster than V6 in the accepted answer (at least in python 3.11.6/numpy 1.26.0 on my machine):

```
def differenceImageV7(img1, img2):
    return np.maximum(img1, img2) - np.minimum(img1, img2)
```

Using the test from the accepted answer (after trivial corrections for python3) and also including the cv2 answer for comparison:

```
differenceImageV2  26091624 0.10563181596808136
differenceImageV3  39184764 0.016355138970538974
differenceImageV4  26091624 1.115124913980253
differenceImageV5  26091624 0.14360517100431025
differenceImageV6  26091624 0.10052977490704507
differenceImageV7  26091624 0.05007318709976971
differenceImageCV2 26091624 0.017319782986305654
```

Worth noting: in the interim V2 also performs much better than it used to.